# Window re-sizing for vertical monitor setup

Tags: windows, window-resize, window-management

Running Windows 7 with two monitors, vertical setup

I want to have more convenient window sizing for vertical monitor setup. Currently there is the normal 'drag window to side of screen' to auto-resize the window to half the screen horizontally. Is there a way to auto-resize to half the screen vertically?

ie. drag to the lower half of the side of the screen to resize to take up the bottom half of the screen and drag to the upper side of the screen to resize to take up the top half.

Is this possible? What software would be best for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in native Windows. Windows 10 might help you a bit however (corner auto-resizse).

I can imagine someone would be able to programm such a solution for Hotkeys, but not by dragging.